# weird bracket & macro syntax in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, macros

I've tried to articulate this into google, but have failed to find anything useful describing it. Here's the code:

```
struct Segdesc gdt[] =
{
  // 0x0 - unused (always faults -- for trapping NULL far pointers)
  SEG_NULL,

  // 0x8 - kernel code segment
  [GD_KT >> 3] = SEG(STA_X | STA_R, 0x0, 0xffffffff, 0),

  // 0x10 - kernel data segment
  [GD_KD >> 3] = SEG(STA_W, 0x0, 0xffffffff, 0),

  // 0x18 - user code segment
  [GD_UT >> 3] = SEG(STA_X | STA_R, 0x0, 0xffffffff, 3),

  // 0x20 - user data segment
  [GD_UD >> 3] = SEG(STA_W, 0x0, 0xffffffff, 3),

  // 0x28 - tss, initialized in trap_init_percpu()
  [GD_TSS0 >> 3] = SEG_NULL
};
```

Can someone explain the meaning of having brackets without an array or pointer in front of them??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This obscure syntax is called a designated initializer and it lets you skip elements when creating an array aggregate.

Take a look at this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[] = {
    1, [2]=3, [5]=7
};
int main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i!=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);i++)
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

It uses the same syntax to skip elements 1, 3, and 4 of the array `a`.

This is what this program prints:

```
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 0
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 0
a[4] = 0
a[5] = 7
```

Your program does the same thing, but it initializes an array of structures, and calculating the indexes into its array aggregate using bit shifts of compile-time constants. You can find the values of these indexes in the comments (0x08, 0x10, 0x18, 0x20, and 0x28).

Comment: Designated initializers are one of the most useful new features of C99.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a [*designated initializer*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). It's a C99 feature. It's useful when defining arrays that are mostly zero, with some values at specific indices.

Cribbing examples off the GCC page:

```
int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
```

is equivalent to

```
int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
```

"Designated initializer" also refers to the ability to initialize structs in an analogous fashion:

```
struct point p = { .y = yvalue, .x = xvalue };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this syntax was introduced in C99, although in a brief google survey, I can't find anything definitive.  In any event, in older C dialects, if you wanted to explicitly initialize, for example, the 3rd element of an array, you had to explicitly list zeroes for the previous elements.  Ie,

```
int foo[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 42 };    // the 42 is arbitrary
```

In modern C, you can enter this instead:

```
int foo[4] = { [3] = 42 };
```

The syntax is kind of obscure, but the intuition, I think, is that what you're doing is roughly the compile time-equivalent of:

```
int foo[4];
foo[3] = 42;
```

Very roughly, again, the example code is equivalent to

```
struct Segdesc gdt[(GD_TSS0 >> 3) + 1];
gdt[0] = SEG_NULL;
gdt[GD_KT >> 3] = ...;
...
gdt[GD_TSS0 >> 3 ] = ...;
```

The advantage of this syntax is that you can more concisely sparsely initialize an array, without having to count array elememnts to get the ones you want to set into the right spots.  Also, this syntax can be applied to static array initializations.

Answer (score 0):

In C the [] and * operator can translate into the same thing when defining. but, when allocating space they have a different syntax.

for instance: a[1] and *(a+1) are identical when dealing with an array of chars.

Comment: Ok, but that in no way whatsoever answers the question.

Comment: After looking at the other answers do you still think that this "in now way whatsoever answers the question"?